# How do I use R to set up 2 boxplots on the same scale?

Tags: r

I've managed to use the `mfrow()` function to set them up side by side, but I'd like them to appear on the same scale, best if on the same plot, actually. How do I do this?

## Set 2 different plots in window

`par(mfrow=c(1,2))`

## Set up 2 different plots: Infected in Utero vs Infected >5 years

```
plot(age.group [in.utero=="yes"], IQ [in.utero=="yes"], xlab="Age group tested", ylab="IQ", main = "Infected in Utero", col=myCols) 

plot(age.group [in.utero=="no"], IQ [in.utero=="no"], xlab="Age group tested", ylab- "IQ", main = "Infected >5 Years", col=myCols)
```

Here's [2 separate plots of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luivd.jpg).

Comment: Perhaps have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904748/creating-multiple-scatter-plots-with-same-axes-in-r). Bottom answer discusses base plotting system. Other answers include the same for ggplot2 and lattice. Your question might be partly a duplicate of that question.

Comment: should it look like this ?
`library(ggplot2) ;`
`ggplot(mtcars, aes(y = hp, x=as.factor(gear) )) + geom_boxplot()`